# PHP json_encode() - SQL limit and AJAX js

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, json

I have this PHP:

```
function getList() {
    $sql = "    SELECT * FROM list  ";        
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode(array('result' => $result));
        $db = null;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
```

and this javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: rootURL + '/' + myAPI,
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(list) {
      var list = list.result; 
      console.log (list);
    }
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
      console.log (" errors: " );
      console.log (jqXHR);
      console.log (textStatus);
      console.log (errorThrown);
    }
});
```

now everything was working fine until I added some rows in the `list` table of my DB.
So now the js `list` result from AJAX is empty:

```
{"result":  }
```

The error I receive from AJAX is:

```
Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="OK", more elements...}
parsererror
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

so I tried to remove: `dataType: "json",` but `result` is still empty.
the only way to make it works is to limit the SQL query like this:

```
$sql = "    SELECT * FROM list LIMIT 9  ";
```

and it works:

```
{"result":
[
{"ID":"1","name":"...","year":"0","description":"...","image_URL":...","state":"..."},
{"ID":"2","name":"...","year":"0","description":"...","image_URL":"...","state":"..."},
{"ID":"3","name":"...","year":"0","description":"...","image_URL":"...","state":"..."},
{"ID":"4","name":"...","year":"0","description":"...","image_URL":...","state":"..."},
{"ID":"5","name":"...","year":"0","description":"...","image_URL":"...","state":"..."},
{"ID":"6","name":"...","year":"0","description":"...","image_URL":"...","state":"..."},
{"ID":"7","name":"...","year":"0","description":"...","image_URL":...","state":"..."},
{"ID":"8","name":"...","year":"0","description":"...","image_URL":"...","state":"..."},
{"ID":"9","name":"...","year":"0","description":"...","image_URL":"...","state":"..."},
]

}
```

I don't understand why there is such a limit. I also tried:

```
$sql = "    SELECT * FROM list LIMIT 10  ";
```

and so on, but the result is still empty:

```
{"result":  }
```

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Don't construct JSON by hand. Use `echo json_encode(array('result' => $result))`.

Comment: Did you try var_dump($result); ? json_encode returns false, and you have to find out why.

Comment: Check the reply in the Network tab of Developer Tools. Your script is probably displaying an error message before the JSON.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer,  `var_dump($result);` show the result I expect, `array(13) ....`
@Barmar, thanks I tried `echo json_encode(array('result' => $result))` but same result and the script gives me no error messages

Comment: @Frank the suggestion of barmar gave you a different output, didn't it ? Keep your eyes open !

Comment: I edited according to the advices

Comment: Have you looked at the AJAX response in Developer Tools?

Comment: Your `responseText` contains the output of `var_dump()`. That's not valid JSON. Check your PHP to see why you're calling `var_dump()`.

Comment: yes sorry edited again.

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual at http://php.net/json_encode. It says:

> All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.

Make sure your data is in UTF-8 encoding in the database. If not you have to convert it first.

Comment: @Frank What is the encoding of your data in the database ?

Comment: it's the correct encoding UTF-8, for instance I have:  `varchar(60) utf8_general_ci
 text utf8_general_ci
tinytext utf8_general_ci
enum('ONGOING', 'COMPLETE') utf8_general_ci`

Answer (score 0):

If it is working with LIMIT 9 and not working with LIMIT 10 so problem is in your records after 9th row so please check your 10th row It may have any 'special character', 'new line character' which is creating problem.

Comment: I tried to remove any of the rows after 9th but same problem, its problem is with any row after 9th, no matters what its content is

Comment: @Frank Programming is not magic, it's logic. There's no magic border line at 9 rows. It matters what the content is. I already told you: **Keep your eyes open!**

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 points I'd like to point out in your code to have a look at. First of all, the construction of the error should be using the `json_encode` function, which will ensure valid format, so instead of doing `echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';` you should do

```
$response = new stdClass();
$response->error = new stdClass();
$response->error->text = $e->getMessage();
echo json_encode($response);
```

Note, that it looks overly complex, but I tried to retain the format you specified in your example.

The other thing is that Javascript will not like `type: 'json'` if the correct headers are not set. So what I suggest your PHP function should look like is this:

```
function getList() {
    $response = new stdClass();
    $sql = "    SELECT * FROM list  ";        
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $response->result = $result;
        unset($db);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {            
        $response->error = new stdClass();
        $response->error->text = $e->getMessage();
    }
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit();
}
```

I hope this helps!